Extracting the Dataframe from the mixed csv file
I have a csv file that has bunch of information in it. From that csv file I want to extract the data into pandas data frame skipping the unnecessary rows. I can't use the skip rows as the start of the data frame row is not fixed.
The column data is also not fixed before the start of actual data that I want to use so I am getting error while loading the data directly into data frame.
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 5 fields in line 340, saw 6
For eg:-
%% Capacity report
  A     B     C 
0 0     Null  Hello
1 0     1     2     3
2 ID    FN    LN    Address        State   Price
3 123   ABC   DEF   312 Main st.   CA       1001
4 345   DEF   HIJ   1008 Main st.  CA       1002

I want to load the data starting from ID till the end of file.
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    for col in range(df.shape[1]):
        if df.iat[row,col] == 'ID':
            row_start = row
            break


Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. It'd help to write a more specific, clearer title, like say "How can I skip rows when reading a dataframe from a CSV if the row where the data starts is not fixed?" Check out [ask] for tips on that and more. You can [edit].

Please provide the raw CSV data. This table is ambiguous since the separator seems to be spaces, but Address contains spaces. Or you could add a space after the initial numbers and use sep=r'\s{2,}'.

Similar question: How to read csv file into pandas, skipping rows until a certain string, then selecting first row after as header and delimiter as |

One solution is to read the file in as a string, and trim off the leading unwanted characters. Then, you can create a pandas data frame using the StringIO engine.
This question and answer may be helpful to you:
Create Pandas DataFrame from a string
